# What does "Installed from: Google Play" mean in Google Play Console?

Tags: google-play-console

In Google Play Console there's a filter called "Installed from: Google Play". What does that mean? I can't find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means an app installed from the Play Store, so not installed from another store or sideloaded.